# Java PrintWriter behavior as socket

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, printwriter, chunking

I made a server in which the sending of the data itself is made like this:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
writer.write(json);
writer.close();
```

How can i know if the server has indeed sent the entire message?

In my client (written in C#), when the json string is long, then i get a certain amount of bytes which is less then the length of the json string (for some reason always a max length of 183 bytes).

The client is using asynchronous connection. How can i know if the server indeed sent the entire message? Is it possible i need to divide a long message into chunks and send them one after the other? I'm just not sure if the problem is in the server or in the client.

Comment: Is this a TCP socket or UDP? For a start, I wouldn't use `PrintWriter`, which swallows exceptions. It's also possible that you're not using the socket properly from the client code.

Comment: I would write a simple client in Java to receive a simple message and see if that works.

Comment: @Jon Skeet its TCP. it's being used for a windows phone app. do you want to see the client C# code?

Comment: @YonatanNir: Well, I would *first* write a console app which could act as the client with a synchronous socket API. Then use a console app using async APIs. Only go to the relatively tricky mobile world once you've got it working in a simpler environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did in the end was adding an header to the message with the size of the message and then checked on the C# side if the size of the received message is the size of the message and if it's not, ask again the socket for data until I got the full message.